# What does <autogenerated>:1 mean when debugging Go package with delve?

Tags: go, vscode-debugger, delve

I was trying to debug a Go package with lots of dependencies, trying to trace function calls across dependencies to get to the bottom of a bug.

Delve – via both CLI and VSCode GUI debugger – followed function calls to a certain depth, but then suddenly refused to go any deeper and instead of allowing me to access the local variables in that function call, produced a cryptic `<autogenerated>:1 (PC: 0x141e850)`.

On VSCode I get this error instead: `go list failed on .: can't load package: package .: no Go files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code`

I know this is kind of vague, but can anybody point me to what this might mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might answer your doubt: [Github: go-delve/delve #1908](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1908)

Read the full thread.

Comment: I couldn't really understand what the problem is although the solution worked. Could you explain to me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this in the future:
The solution is to set breakpoints IN the functions that are getting called as well. I tried this, and it does in fact follow the function calls properly.